# Laravel: Class 'App\DB' not found

Tags: php, class, laravel-5, namespaces

I am trying to use `DB` class to run query. I have used it in my controller like this:

```
use \DB;
```

And I am using it in my code like this:

```
$changeCar = DB::select(DB::raw($query));
```

I have tried including it like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB
```

But still the same. Also, tried it with the backslash in the code and not including it like this:

```
$changeCar = \DB::select(\DB::raw($query));
```

My Code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use \DB;


class TicketsController extends Controller
{
    public function myTickets()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $changeCar = DB::select(DB::raw($query));
    }
}
```

Still the same. What am I doing wrong here? Any help?

P.S: My `laravel` version is `5.4.33`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DB` is a facade in Laravel. So just doing `Use DB;` should work. Can you check if you have `opcache` enabled on your php.ini ?

Look up `php.ini` for `opcache_enabled=1` and change the value to 0. Then restart your nginx/apache server and try again.

Comment: I tried what you told me to. But still the same error.

Comment: Can you please paste your controller code (or pseudo code) here please? Maybe the use statements have something wrong in them.

Comment: Please try `Use DB;` and not use `\DB`

Comment: hmm.. very weird. Are you certain the error message says `Class App\DB not found` ? It should be `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found`

Just trying to find the root.

What happens when you remove the line `$user = Auth::user();` ? Could be a problem in your `User` model. Tough to tell without seeing the code there.

Comment: Okay, got it. It was actually calling a method from tickets model where DB was being using but not included hence the App\DB not found error. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by adding the following to the top of my model:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

in the correct class should work. This answer just helped me. I was not being keen on which class should be modified. I was modifying a different class that does not require the DB class. I was adding it in DatabaseSeeder.php instead of the correct file needing it that has been UserSeeder.php

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers